# Is this a bad way to use ternary if else with promises in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ternary if else for calling different APIs(API calls are stored in another file).

```
(this.props.item === "burger" ? burgerObj.GetBurger (this.props.burger_id) : pizzaObj.GetPizza (this.props.pizza_id)) // burgerObj and pizzaObj are objects of their respective classes
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.status === 400) {
              console.log ("Bad Request")
            }
            else {
                response.json()
                .then((findresponse) => {
                    this.prepareFood(findresponse) // Some function call
                })
            }
        })
        .catch ((e) => {
            console.log (e)
        })
    }


// API calls in different classes. Same is for GetPizza
GetBurger(burger_id) {
return fetch(url + 'burgerId' + burger_id , {
  headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authorization,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
```

}

Is this a wrong way of handling such calls. Because when I'm using this API calling is working fine but the code never reaches promise (.then((response) => {  - line no. 2). If I check Network I can see the response returned from API. Sorry if I am wrong somewhere I'm still new to React. Please help me.

Comment: It might be easier to work with a factory function that returns a promise based on the props

Comment: Just to be sure - it doesn't reach `catch`, either?

Comment: Can you give me some more information on using factory function here and No, it doesn't reach catch

Comment: Try wrapping the whole `.then((... console.log(e)})` in parenthesis: `( .then((.... console.log(e)})  )`.

Comment: Maybe you could put the result of the ternary operation in a temp variable and then `.then`-ing that.

Comment: Wrapping doesnt works either.

Comment: Using temporary variable works but is it a good way ?

Comment: I don't see why not, it feels cleaner than putting it all in one line in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, ok I'll use that but I also want to know what's wrong in my code,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **Ternary** is ok. But you can you can use `Async/Await` to clean up callbacks -

```
const { item, burger_id, pizza_id} = this.props;

function fetchWrapper(url) {
    fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer${authorization}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
        .then(data => { return { data, error: null }; })
        .catch(error => { return { error, data: null }; });
}

// API calls in different classes. Same is for GetPizza
async function GetBurgerAsync(burgerId) {
    let response = await fetchWrapper(`url burgerId${burgerId}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}


const foodType = item === 'burger' ? GetBurgerAsync(burger_id) : GetPizzaAsync(pizza_id);
if (foodType.data) {
    this.prepareFood(foodType);
}
```

Edit: refactored, wrapping `fetch` as only url should change on every call. Token should be same across all calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer